# Divergence of a vector multiplied by dot product

Tags: vectors, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

If I am correct, then
$\operatorname{div} [(\vec A\cdot \vec B)\vec C] = (\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec C + \vec C \cdot \nabla (\vec A\cdot\vec B)= (\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec C+ \vec C\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B+\vec C\cdot(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A+\vec C\cdot(\vec A\times(\nabla\times\vec B))+ \vec C\cdot(\vec B\times(\nabla\times\vec A))$

When $\vec A=\vec C$  it will be reduced to $\operatorname{div}[(\vec A\cdot \vec B)\vec A]=(\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec A + \vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B+\vec A\cdot(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A+\vec A\cdot(\vec B\times(\nabla\times\vec A))$

Is there any possibility that it could be reduced to \begin{equation}\operatorname{div}[(\vec A\cdot\vec B)\vec A]=\vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B + \vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A\qquad (*)\end{equation}? I've seen this expression, but I'm not sure whether it's correct or not.

UPD: I understood that I have a magnetic field as $\vec A$ in my task (where I've seen $(*)$ expression), so it could explain why there wasn't $(\vec A \cdot\vec B )\operatorname{div}\vec A $ term, but I still have difficulties with getting $\vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A$ term.

If I expand the cross product, I get
$$\vec A\cdot(\vec B\times(\nabla\times\vec A))=\vec A\cdot(\nabla_{A}(\vec B\cdot \vec A)-(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A )$$
What should I do to get $\vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A$?

Comment: This is a math question, not a physics one.

Comment: I just saw similar questions in this section. If this is really far from the topic, then I will delete the question.

Comment: Updated. I thought that the divergence of scalar doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Stack Exchange posts are version controlled, so please [do not make your post look like a revision table](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/25301). Instead, just seamlessly integrate the new material into the post. There is an edit history button at the bottom of the post for those interested in seeing what changed.

Comment: I'll try next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct expression is
$$
\begin{aligned}
   \operatorname{div}[(\vec A\cdot\vec B)\vec A]
   &= (\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec A 
   + \vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B 
   + \vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A   \\
   &= (\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec A 
   + \vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B
   +\vec A\cdot(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A
   +\vec A\cdot(\vec B\times(\nabla\times\vec A))
\end{aligned}
$$
In order to see that these two are the same, one could use so-called BAC-minus-CAB rule.

Finally, the last formula of yours is wrong when $\operatorname{div} A \neq 0$.

Comment: I have some difficulties: $(\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec A+\vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B+\vec A\cdot(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A+\vec A\cdot(\vec B\times(\nabla\times\vec A))=(\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec A+\vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B+\vec A\cdot(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A+\vec A\cdot(\nabla_{A}(\vec B\cdot \vec A)-(\vec B\cdot\nabla)\vec A )=(\vec A \cdot \vec B) \operatorname{div} \vec A+\vec A\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec B+\vec A\cdot\nabla_{A}(\vec B\cdot \vec A)$. What should I do to get $\vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A$

Comment: I also understand that I have a magnetic field as $\vec A$ in my problem, so it could explain why there wasn't $(\vec A\cdot\vec B)\operatorname{div} \vec A$, but I still have difficulties with another term.

Comment: @Kubrick I’m sorry but it’s hard to understand what is the problem. Please do not put formulas in comments, put them in the main text, enumerate them and refer them by labels.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @Kubrick answer to your last question is that $\vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A$ is the same as $\vec A\cdot \nabla_{A}(\vec B\cdot \vec A)$.

Comment: I've checked it by expanding it by coordinates. Is it possible to notice it without that?

Comment: @Kubrick yes, it is literally the same thing with terms rearranged.

Comment: Could you explain how exactly did you notice that? I'm also interested in how did you get your first equation before the second, it must be some rule for that, I guess.

Comment: @Kubrick yes, you’re right, there is a rule. Basically it says that you operate with $\nabla$ just if it is an usual vector, but you need to track the record of what the derivative acts upon. Just as in the example with the BAC-minus-CAB rule. There is a rule for simple vectors and you can use with $\nabla$ as well, just put these subscripts denoting what derivative acts on as you did above $\nabla_A$. If there is no subscript, it means that derivative acts on everything on the right. As long as you remember it, you can rearrange terms.

Comment: I know about this feature of the vector operator $\nabla$, I also know the rule $\operatorname{div}(f\vec A)=f\operatorname{div}\vec A+\vec A\cdot\nabla f$, but it does not look obvious to your actions with the so-called material derivatives. It also seems you know that $\vec B\cdot(\vec A\cdot\nabla)\vec A=\vec A\cdot \nabla_{A}(\vec B\cdot \vec A)$ without checking it by coordinates (maybe I'm wrong). Maybe it is the same rule, but it looks rather exotic in this case.

Comment: @Kubrick yes, it’s obvious to me. I guess it will become obvious to you in some time as well. Looks like you understand all the important stuff, so I consider my job done here.

Comment: Well, I’ll try to understand this deeper and maybe it will become intuitive to me. Anyway, thanks for the answers.